# Detecting reasons for scp of glob failing

Tags: bash, permissions, scp

I am `scp`-ing some files from a remote host in a script. I want to know if anything fails, most commonly due to permissions issues. The files being copied belong to a different user and sometimes the script to change file permissions doesn't run. One of the sets of files being copied is a glob which might be empty, so right now the script contains a line that looks like this `scp -p remote:*.pattern curdir`. For all the other copy commands, I simply check the return code, but that doesn't work here, as it's possible the glob is simply empty. What's the best way to check whether the scp has non-zero return code just because there are no files matching the glob as opposed to other issues like bad permissions on the parent directory or on the files themselves?

Comment: I get a return code of 1, for the same command with an empty glob

Answer (score 0):

Is using ssh do display a list of files on remote host a possible solution:

```
ssh remote "find ./ -type f -name '*.pattern'"
```

You can then compare local list of file to remote one, using `diff` for example, or `wc -l` for line count.